# ggplot non-numeric argument to binary operator from aggregated data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created an aggregate with this code.

```
test=aggregate(Concentration~Day,data=linoleic_CL,function(x) c(Mean=mean(x),SD=sd(x),T=t.test(x,mu=0)[3]))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(test,aes(x=Day,y=Concentration[,"Mean"]))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Concentration[,"Mean"]-Concentration[,"SD"],ymax=Concentration[,"Mean"]+Concentration[,"SD"]),position=position_dodge(0.9),width=0.25)
```

returns

> Error in `geom_errorbar()`:
> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
> Caused by error in `Concentration[, "Mean"] - Concentration[, "SD"]`:
> ! non-numeric argument to binary operator

I tried the `as.numeric()` solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327736/non-numeric-argument-to-binary-in-geom-errorbar), but I don't know if I'm not doing it right or something, but `class(test$Concentration[1])` (0.0888567072190236) still returns `[1] "list"`

Comment: does adding `test <- do.call('cbind.data.frame', test)` help?

Comment: I think what you try is not possible in this way, have a look here: See this post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503821/perform-t-test-using-aggregate-function-in-r>

Comment: it's fine for a one-sample test

Comment: That didn't change it, rawr.

Comment: The issue is with the geom_errorbar function, TarJae. The T-test works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`test <- do.call('cbind.data.frame', test)` then `test$Concentration.Mean=as.numeric(test$Concentration.Mean)` worked.